# React-Native, Android bundleRelease failure at :app:createReleaseExpoManifest

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo

Been having an issue with running `'./gradlew bundleRelease`.. The output of that command is..

Some extra context, I had to go into the regular fs-extra node_modules folder to change the `catch {` to `catch (error) {`

> Task :app:createReleaseExpoManifest FAILED
> /node_modules/@expo/config/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/remove/rimraf.js:305
>
> ```
>  } catch {}
>          ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
> at createScript (vm.js:80:10)

I've searched through a lot of the stackoverflow and github issues/responses. Unable to find a solution to this.. Attempts include, fixing all of the fs-extra package catch errors with `catch (error) {`

Also, checked the node version. Here is a list of node version including the default..

> ```
>      v8.9.0
>     v8.17.0
>     v12.8.1
>     v15.5.0
> ```
>
> ->     v15.11.0
> system default -> 15.11.0 (-> v15.11.0)

Usually, this turns out to be a Node version error. However, doesn't seem to work on the latest Node version that I have installed.